# How to read console in Java in debug mode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Run following program in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
package org.stepic.java;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();

        //try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner("1 2 3 4 5 6 7")) {
            int i = 0;
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    Integer number = scan.nextInt();
                    if((i++ % 2) == 1) deque.add(number);
                } else {
                    scan.next();
                }
            }

            Iterator<Integer> it = deque.descendingIterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Integer num = it.next();
                System.out.printf("%s ", num.toString());
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it, I can enter some in console then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and it will be stored in scanner. If I do same thing in debugger, IDEA just skips line:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
```

and I can't enter anything. In this case scanner buf is empty. How to enter text in console in debug mode?

Comment: Which is your Java version / your IJ version / the path of the executable file from the first line in console? Where do you put the breakpoint? The debug mode works fine for me.

Comment: Java 1.8, open JDK: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/...`, breakpoint in line `int i = 0;`...

Answer (score 0):

Stdin works in debug mode (F5) correctly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    if( scan.hasNext() ) {
        System.out.println("Got " + scan.next());
    }
}
```

It works in debug mode, with breakpoint on println.

Maybe you just not noticed that in debug mode [console] is not default tab and you try to enter text to [debugger] window?

Comment: It works for F5 (run), however read nothing by Ctrl-А5 (debug). So this solution does not work, sorry.

Comment: F5 is debug in my settings

Comment: I see, however debug does not work for me for some reason. Console is not default, but I switch to Console of course :)

Comment: So Your solution does not work for me, need some other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `scan.next()` or something similar in your Variable Watch. Remove that and it may work correctly then. I had similar problems with Stack<>()

Comment: Do not have such.